# How to disable "Windows Genuine Advantage Notification Installer" popup in a script?

Tags: windows, unattended

Some time ago my Windows XP workstations started to show "Windows Genuine Advantage Notification Installer" popup every time I login as an administrator. How to get rid of it using a script? I know that I have a genuine Windows.

Comment: Why is this Community Wiki?

Comment: Because I've answered to my own question. This way I could accept my own answer, which is the most voted one.

Comment: eHow has answered the question as well:  http://www.ehow.com/how_2189436_remove-windows-genuine-advantage-notifications.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the following solution. This popup was shown by Windows Scheduler in a job named WGASetup. I just needed to get rid of it.

It would be easy to delete this job, but I think Windows Update, in its helpfulness would recreate it. I needed to disable this job. It is fairy easy to do using job properties window but not so easy using a script.

I've googled a bit and found this program:
ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/ResKit/win2000/jt.zip

The batch file looks like this:

```
jt.exe /lj %windir%\Tasks\WGASetup.job /sj Suspend=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you have a genuine windows, who care about the notifier. Just let him install himself, He'll do his job of checking your genuiness and then you problem will be solved... You'll never heard about him anymore after...

Comment: Until the next time Microsoft decide to trigger it...

Comment: lol :P Yeah well...

Comment: WGA has problems:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Genuine_Advantage#Criticisms

This software stays in memory, consuming resources. It phones home on regular basis and only MS knows what it sends. There are also examples of false positives. I do not want it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes in registry editor on following key..

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MicrosoftWindows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Notify

and you can easily [remove Windows Genuine Notification without validation](http://microsoft-support-squad.blogspot.in/2012/06/remove-windows-genuine-notification.html).

Answer (score 0):

click "start" ,"Search", "for files and folders". Search for "WGA" and delete the prefetch, task, and everything under the system 32 folder- that is the folder that windows update stored the files in the 1st place. That should get rid of the "windows genuine advantage notification installer".
Hope this helps.